# Difference between "after" and "since"

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

I have a question related to the usage of "Since" and "after". Actually I found these three sentences on news articles. And I have seen a large number results both in "news" and "Ngrams". Are all these sentence using "after" is correct. I think "since" would be the preferred choice here. And my question is, is the third sentence is correct as written?

1- But, while in April, it was suggested that these three seats would be the sole focus of the Scottish Labour campaign, that attitude has changed **after** the local elections.

2- A 34-stone man mountain who binged on £5,000 of takeaways a year has shared intimate photos of how his body has changed **after** losing more than 14 stone in just ten months.

3-Prof David Kipping, of New York’s Columbia University, has been using the Kepler Space Telescope to search for moons around other worlds for years, without success.
‘We’ve had candidates in the past and investigated them, and most of them have evaporated,’ he said. But it seems his luck has changed **after** he and his team spotted larger-than-expected dips in the amount of light visible as a planet passed in front of Sun-sized star Kepler 1625.

Comment: So after counting out instances of the two words without regard to context (Ngrams) and quoting three randomly chosen examples of sentences using "after" from the vast reaches of the interweb, you're asking if the two words are synonyms? I'm just trying to be clear.  Noting that the words are close enough that they bear little difference to any but the most sensitive and nuanced eye, I'm left wondering why it matters?  The sample sentences look grammatically sound, if debatable on sylistic merit.

Comment: @Rob_Ster Thanks. I know that "since" is mostly used with present perfect and present perfect continuous tense. But I was not sure if the word "after" could mean almost the same in the circumstances in which the example sentences were used.

Comment: [Here is the rule:](https://www.englishforums.com/English/UsageOfSinceAndAfter/bbnndz/post.htm) When using a perfect form of a verb to indicate an action continuing into the future, use "since." When using the past tense of a verb to indicate action happening at a point in the past, but not necessarily continuing, use "after." But I agree with Rob that it's more a matter of style, not really a "rule of grammar" (most people would use ***since*** in OP's examples, but I wouldn't say ***after*** is "invalid"; to me it's just it's just slightly "awkward").